# MSSQL user defined data type creation time

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

How to get `user defined data type` (not table type) creation time in `MSSQL`?

`sys.types` has no appropriate column and types are not listed in `sys.all_objects`, so it looks like something not supported by `SQL server`.

Another thing that potentially hints this is not available is that most of other object types have both create_date/modify_date. Types have no `ALTER` command so they definitely have no modify date.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving answer as **this is not possible** for now, because that's what I've found so far.